# Calling an overloaded operator from dll in GUI

Tags: c#

I have a GUI application with another program referenced with .dll. In calling the functions to the GUI buttons, I have difficulty getting the overloaded '+' and '-' methods to work.

Basically, how do I call the overloaded versions of those in my GUI?

Comment: An overloaded method has a particular signature.  You just call it with what it expects.  You will need to post example code if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: Are you talking about `+=` and `-=` as operators that call the `add` and `remove` accessors of an event? Please provide more detail, and show some code.